# Android Fabric Twitter and Digits trouble

Tags: android, twitter-fabric, twitter-digits

i installed Fabric plugin in Android studio. Chose Digits and add some code by suggestions of it.
Got this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.digits.sdk.android.DigitsAuthButton.setCallback(com.digits.sdk.android.AuthCallback)' on a null object reference.
```

So, the problem is here(maybe):

```
phoneButton.setCallback(new AuthCallback() {
            @Override
            public void success(DigitsSession digitsSession, String phoneNumber) {

            }

            @Override
            public void failure(DigitsException e) {

            }
        });
```

Also i had same problems with Twitter part of plugin.
Any ideas?
Thank you for attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with the AuthCallback, your **phoneButton** object is null, possibly because it wasn't retrieved from the layout properly.

Comment: This was nearly close. I forgot to add 'setContentView(...)' in onCreate method of MainActivity.